# how to pass optional parameter in linq where condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a action in MVC controller

```
public ActionResult ExportExcel(string ReportType,DateTime? FromDate,DateTime? ToDate)
{
     var query = UnitOfWork.RepoTestResAnalysis.GetAll();
     var QueryData = query.Where(s => s.MSO == ms && (FromDate != null && (s.TEST_DATE.Value >= FromDate)) && (ToDate!=null && (s.TEST_DATE.Value<=ToDate))).ToList();
}
```

Now If `FromDate` and `ToDate` are null then I am getting `QueryData` Count is Zero. But I need all records. So Can anyone tell me how can I get expected result. While `FromDate` & `ToDate` has value then I am getting expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the information you have provided

**Change you below statement:**

```
var QueryData = query.Where(s => s.MSO == ms && (FromDate != null && (s.TEST_DATE.Value >= FromDate)) && (ToDate!=null && (s.TEST_DATE.Value<=ToDate))).ToList();
```

**To**

```
var QueryData = query.Where(s => s.MSO == ms && (FromDate == null || (s.TEST_DATE.Value >= FromDate)) && (ToDate == null || (s.TEST_DATE.Value<=ToDate))).ToList();
```

If the `FromDate` Or `ToDate` will be equal to `NULL`, it won't check them against `s.TEST_DATE.Value`.

Comment: Your post has been precious. I had quite a complex query where I needed to check against nullable variables, I was getting exceptions because I was checking their null condition with an AND (as if it were an if clause IF A != NULL AND A.METHODS()) while I need to think of them as a OR. If a variable is null, then I don't need to check for the rest of its clause because it does not add any filter to the query, if it's not null then its clause does filter. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below also:
Change QueryData assignment to:

```
var QueryData = query.Where(s => s.MSO == ms && 
(s.TEST_DATE.Value >= (FromDate ?? DateTime.MinValue)) && 
(s.TEST_DATE.Value <= (ToDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I will be glad if my code can help anybody.
I think following implementation will be the short and easy to read:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(string ReportType, DateTime? FromDate, DateTime? ToDate)
{
    var query = UnitOfWork.RepoTestResAnalysis.GetAll();
    var QueryData = query.Where(x => x.DateField >= (FromDate ?? x.DateField) && x.DateField <= (ToDate ?? x.DateField).ToList();                 
}
```